# Why am I getting a compiler error when I'm trying to print string return?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

I think that this is a overloading operator error but I don't see why it assumes I'm trying to use overload operator.

```
string Customer::getCustomerName() 
{
    return customerName;
}

string Customer::getCustomerLicense()
{
    return customerLicense;
}

Date* Customer::getCustomerBirthday()
{
    return customerBirthday;
}

void Customer::printCustomerObject()
{
    cout << getCustomerName(); // No operator "<<" matches these operands
}                                 ERROR CODE: E0349
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] to help diagnose the problem better

Comment: What exactly makes you *"think that this is a overloading operator error"* ?

Comment: We don't know what operands the compiler thinks are in the std::cout call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't include the standard string header.
`#include <string>`